# Для чего нужен глобальный атрибут slot в спецификации HTML?

Tags: html, атрибуты

Не пойму для чего нужен глобальный атрибут slot в спецификации HTML? Что он делает, как работает? 
https://www.w3.org/TR/dom41/#nodes-shadow-tree-slots

Comment: [The <slot> element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#slots)

Comment: @Grundy И что? Что он делает, как работает? Там вообще все по-английски, непонятно

Comment: Дырка в shadow DOM, в которую можно что-нибудь вставить

Comment: @Grundy Что за дырка, что вставить? Можно подробнее? Как это работает , для чего нужно можете объяснить? Или вы сами не понимаете как это работает?